# DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, 16.04, spdif

description at

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio

no longer works on ubuntu 16.04

I end up in

> rate_lavr.c:20:38: fatal error: libavresample/avresample.h: No such
>   file or directory

when compiling alsa-plugins-1.1.0

Comment: Actually reading through a whole other page for figuring out what you want to achieve, or reproducing the steps you did is not so cool.

Comment: I thought it was clear that I try to compile the alsa plugin as described on that page and that no longer works on 16.04 as I get an error.
its under the header "Build the plugins:"

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by installing libavresample-dev package

```
sudo apt-get install libavresample-dev
```